# Regular expression - Trouble with identifying the appropriate character class needed (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that only prints out the first names from the attached document (only the data within the table, I haven't been using the stuff below but will work this in eventually).

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/files/examplePhoneEmailDirectory.pdf

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import re
import pyperclip

nameRegex = re.compile(r'''
 
[a-zA-Z]+    # first name
\s          # space
[a-zA-Z]+    # last name

''', re.VERBOSE)

text = pyperclip.paste()
extractedText = nameRegex.findall(text)

print(extractedText)
```

The problem that I'm facing is that when I run the code I get something like the following: Jessie Mckayjmckay

It is giving me the first name, last name and the letters in their email address, stopping at the first number. I've tried to solve this by adding a negative custom character class like this [^\s]. My thinking was that the code would recognise the space after the last name and stop. However, this does not work, I suspect it has something to do with the formatting of the document.

Would anyone be able to help me on this?

Comment: Did you tried printing the contents of the pdf and checking it's format? Something like in what format the data is being printed.

Comment: The beginning of first line of the file is `aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaa`. Does that contain a "first name"? Please post a *tiny* part of that file (or better, a file that contain more than `a`'s and spaces) in your question and ditch the link, in part because links have a way of being broken, rendering your question forever incomplete. (Questions live forever on SO, you know.) That way users can use the same data to demonstrate answers. I'm sure I've seen the content of that file in another question a month or two ago, so your question may turn out to be a "duplicate" and be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After printing output of data I noticed your regex matches also emails and first names togerther as there is a space between them. So my idea is to make sure that first letter of each word is capital ( as data is formated this way):

```
import re
import pyperclip

nameRegex = re.compile(r'''
 
[A-Z][a-z]+   # first name
\s+          # space
[A-Z][a-z]+    # last name

''', re.VERBOSE)

text = pyperclip.paste()

extractedText = nameRegex.findall(text)

print(extractedText)
```

Try that :)

I got below result ( part of the result):

```
['Jessie Mckay', 'Tom Jordan', 'Clayton Cross', 'Rayford Sutton', 'Jerome Gentry', 'Weldon Camacho', 'Quinton Franks', 'Adam Hubbard', 'Jarred Fox', 'Arnoldo Parker', 'Sid Mcdaniel', 'Raymon Combs', 'Ervin Francis', 'Gilberto Austin', 'Lino Barlow', 'Stacey Shepherd', 'Roscoe Terry', 'Eddie Meadows', 'Carlos Simpson', 'Jerome Manning', 'Hong Erickson', 'Burt Graham', 'Mario Sloan', 'Jeffry Mcintosh', 'Owen Malone', 'Jamar Gilbert', 'Guadalupe Ramsey', 'Chet Ramsey', 'Lester Finch', 'Mason Marquez', 'Olen Boyer', 'Sherman Gamble', 'Gerry Mccarthy', 'Jon Jefferson', 'Cristopher Maddox', 'Abel Talley', 'Jerrod Hurst', 'Ezra Pickett', 'Delbert Mcintyre', 'Tom Wilkins', 'Deandre Schneider', 'Louie Gross', 'Cary Mathews', 'Clinton Hernandez', 'Sylvester Goodman', 'Efren Daniels', 'Myles Knapp', 'Trey Hendrix', 'Gerardo Gonzales', 'Collin Wilkinson', 'Hubert Moore', 'Rudolph Joyce', 'Raymundo Griffin', 'Stanton Burris', 'Newton Huff', 'Lonnie Gibson', 'Newton Mendez', 'Dominic Kane', 'Rey Alvarado', 'Maxwell Pittman', 'Freddy Nolan', 'Quentin Kane', 'Marcelo Owens', 'Saul Warner', 'Giuseppe Edwards', 'Glen Duffy', 'Johnson Bird', 'Lon Mays', 'Orval Jones', 'Stefan Wiley', 'Dewayne Vincent', 'Elmo Morton', 'Trenton Randolph', 'Alonzo Noble', 'Stephan Callahan', 'Merrill Morin', 'Antonia Vasquez', 'Jerrod Horne', 'Sammie Blanchard', 'Renaldo Nielsen', 'Rick Logan', 'Xavier Sexton', 'Delmer Chambers', 'Melvin Dixon', 'Randell Wright', 'Kasey Mcbride', 'Long Cohen', 'Hunter Walton', 'Jacques Dean', 'Nicky Cleveland', 'Heath Reeves', 'Dannie Castro', 'Malcolm Pickett', 'Emil Bryant', 'Lonny Trevino',
```

Comment: Well I just copied whole table to clipboard and got correct results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've just tried adding this in and the same problem as before occurs for me?

Comment: Well do you copy the table only?

Comment: Oh wait, so if I copy the whole table it works, but if I only copy the first page then it doesn't work. That's strange. Do you know why that is? (sorry only just saw your comment I'm new to stackoverflow still getting to used to it)

Comment: works for me when copying first page. Just be precise when selecting table and  copying, thats the key I guess :)